# ObjectMapper failed to serialize response. From API Response using AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: swift, model, response

In swift, I am using AlamofireObjectMapper. But I am getting error **"ObjectMapper failed to serialize response."** here is my api response and model please give me the solution. In response, not any null value.

This is API response

```
{"status":true,"result":[{"id":"246","sortname":"ZW","name":"Zimbabwe","phonecode":"263"},{"id":"245","sortname":"ZM","name":"Zambia","phonecode":"260"},{"id":"202","sortname":"ZA","name":"South Africa","phonecode":"27"},{"id":"244","sortname":"YU","name":"Yugoslavia","phonecode":"38"},{"id":"141","sortname":"YT","name":"Mayotte","phonecode":"269"},{"id":"243","sortname":"YE","name":"Yemen","phonecode":"967"},{"id":"91","sortname":"XU","name":"Guernsey and Alderney","phonecode":"44"}]}
```

This is calling API

```
   Alamofire.request(geturl, method: .get).responseArray { [weak self] (response: DataResponse<[countrymodel]>) in

        print(response)
              switch response.result {
        case .success(let assignments):

            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(realm.objects(countrymodel.self))
                realm.add(assignments, update: true)
            }
            for a in assignments{
                print(a)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
           print(".... . .. . .. . .")
        }

    }
```

Here is my Model class

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class countrymodel: Object, Mappable{

    enum Status: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
        case open, closed, cancelled
        var description : String {
            switch self {
            case .open: return "Open"
            case .closed: return "Closed"
            case .cancelled: return "Cancelled"
            }
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var sortname = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var phonecode = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- (map["id"])
        sortname <- map["sortname"]
        name <- map["name"]
        phonecode <- map["phonecode"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response isn't an array its a dictionary and inside it there is an array called `result` , so the serialization fails , you may make it

```
Alamofire.request(geturl, method: .get).responseJSON
```

and parse that array only

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:
change this code

```
params).responseArray(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<[countrymodel]>) in
```

like this:

```
params).responseObject {(response: DataResponse<countrymodel>) in
```